# $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid b^x < y\}$ is nonempty

Tags: analysis

Let $1<b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. I have proved that $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid b^x < y\}$ is nonempty when $y > 1$. Please give me any hint how to show that $A$ is nonempty when $y\leq 1$.

Comment: It depends on your definition of $b^x$

Comment: I want to delete this post..

Comment: $x<0$ basically lets you convert $b$ to $1/b$ and use your previous proof.

Comment: If $y = 1$, there won't be $x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $b^{x}<1$ for $b=1$.

Comment: @Katlus: Is there not a "delete" link in the bottom left of your post (by "link," "edit," etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequences $x_n=-n$ and $b_n = b^{x_n}$. Ask what the limit of $b_n$ is and use facts about limits.